# jacoco-aggregate give an empty report

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to do a jacoco-aggregate to send it to sonarqube according to this post:
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151

Apparently it is needed to use the xml format aggregated now because SonarQube does not use the exec file anymore according to this warning on SonarQube (But I can't see where it is officially stated besides a forum post and it was working some months ago on my project with exec files)

[image]

My pom architecture is like this:

```
-root
  --child1
  -- common
  -- coverage
  -- etc
```

My root pom look like this (only the interesting part about jacoco)

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.toto.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My child1 and common pom look like this

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.toto.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- need to add this in order for the correct to be passed, and create the jacoco.exec -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My coverage pom look like this:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.toto.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>coverage</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

<!-- Used to determine which module should be aggregated -->
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.toto.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
            <version1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.toto.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report-aggregate</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I run a mvn clean install I see the following result in folders:

```
- root
  -- child1
  ----target
  ------jacoco.exec
  --common
  ----target
  ------jacoco.exec
  --coverage
  --- target
  -----site
  -------jacoco-aggregate
  ---------jacoco.xml (The famous file I need to pass to sonarqube)
```

I do a mvn verify on the root parent and in debug mode I see that I pass in jacoco-aggregate method in the createRepport. However the result is empty and I don't understand why. If I open the index.html in the coverage part, I get the following result:

[image]

There is no coverage added and I don't understand why, the jacoco.exec have info in it so I don't understand why it's not aggregated correctly in the jacoco-aggregate. I make sure to be as close as the jacoco-example at: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/tree/master/jacoco-maven-plugin.test/it/it-report-aggregate and when I try this test I can see the following result:

[image]

But I can't get the same result on my end

Comment: For SonarQube you don't need to create an aggregate report... SonarQube uses the `*.exec` files...

Comment: are you trying to do coverage on jars you have in the "aggregate" project?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes it was working like that with the *.exec file before but I don't see any coverage on sonaQube and I have a warning that reportPath is no longer supported and I need to use xmlReportPath with xml format. (But it's not clear when the change was done and it's officially stated on SonarQube)

Comment: @HenningLuther yes I am trying to cover the lines/methods/classes I have on my different folder (child1, common etc...)

Comment: ok. so i guess there should be some jacoco.exec be generated for the child modules which than gets aggregated with the aggregate. you are sure your tests did run and can you see specific files for those childs

Comment: yes I can see the jacoco exec for my different child modules, but when i try to aggregate them in the coverage module, the jacoco-aggregate folder gave me an aggregate report with empty results for each of my child modules